# algolia-sanity updating doesn't work nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, algolia, sanity

i am trying to automatically update my algolia index by using the sanity-algolia package and the sanity webhook (i am using the legacy webhook) but it doesn't work.
Here's my /api/route.js file

```
import indexer from "sanity-algolia";
import { client } from "../../lib/client";
import { algolia } from "../../lib/algolia";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function POST(req) {
  const sanityAlgolia = indexer(
    {
      product: {
        index: algolia.initIndex("dev_gamestore"),
        projection: `
          name,
          "path": slug.current,
          image,
          price
        `,
      },
    },
    (document) => {
      console.log(document);
      switch (document._type) {
        case "product":
          return {
            name: document.name,
            path: document.path,
            price: document.price,
            image: document.image,
          };
        default:
          return document;
      }
    }
  );

  return sanityAlgolia
    .webhookSync(client, req.body)
    .then(() => NextResponse.json({ msg: "lessgoo" }))
    .catch((err) => {
      let error_response = {
        status: "error",
        msg: err,
      };
      return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(error_response));
    });
}
```

and as i said using the legacy webhook proposed in the sanity-algolia package's github page.
Plz help i've been stuck for a whole week :/

Answer (score 2):

btw for anyone seeing this the problem i had was getting data from request.body since it should be a promise, here's the working file:

```
import indexer from "sanity-algolia";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

import { client } from "../../lib/client";
import { algolia } from "../../lib/algolia";

export async function POST(req) {
  try {
    const sanityAlgolia = indexer(
      {
        product: {
          index: algolia.initIndex("dev_gamestore"),
        },
      },
      (document) => {
        console.log(document);
        switch (document._type) {
          case "product":
            return {
              name: document.name,
              path: document.slug["current"],
              price: document.price,
              image: document.image,
            };
          default:
            return document;
        }
      }
    );

    const body = await req.json();

    const webhook = await sanityAlgolia.webhookSync(client, body);

    return webhook && NextResponse.json({ msg: "lessgoo" });
  } catch (err) {
    let error_response = {
      status: "error",
      msg: err,
    };
    return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(error_response));
  }
}
```